# Get a Winstation Name from a Process ID

Tags: c, windows, winapi, msdn

I am trying to get the name of the winstation (for example "winsta0") that a separate process has opened using only its Process ID. I can't find anything that does this on MSDN. They only seem to have GetProcessWindowStation() which only works for your own process.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: 
Maybe this is part of the puzzle...

BOOL ProcessIdToSessionId(
  __in   DWORD dwProcessId,
  __out  DWORD *pSessionId
);

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to use EnumWindowStations(), EnumDesktops(), EnumDesktopWindows(), and GetWindowThreadProcessId() to look at all running windows until you find one that matches the desired process ID.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had a look at the API functions but hit the same dead end as you.  Remy's suggestion should work as long as the target process creates one or more top-level windows.  The following, crazy idea also occured to me:

1. Use VirtualAllocEx() to allocate some executable memory in the target process
2. Use WriteProcessMemory() to write some code into that memory
3. Use CreateRemoteThread() to execute the code in that process

The injected code would call GetProcessWindowStation() and then use an IPC mechanism to send it back to your process.  After you get it, use VirtualFreeEx() to restore the target process's orginal address space.  There are some additional issues using this on another user's process, but it should still work if you run as administrator.